# Why wouldn't my image display (from gallery) when in portrait mode?

Tags: java, android-intent, camera, android

I have used this code to start an intent to pick a picture from the tablet's gallery.

```
Intent pick_picture_intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pick_picture_intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(pick_picture_intent, PICK_PICTURE);
```

Everything works fine, with the startActivityForResult(), having the image placed into a image view. (ONLY IN LANDSCAPE MODE), however, when I try doing the same thing in PORTRAIT MODE, it doesn't work.

Code in `startActivityFroResult()`:

```
if(data != null && data.getData() != null) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
}

 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();


try {
     String imagePath = cursor.getString(0);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

     myLayout.addView(imageView);

 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
      cursor.close();
 }
```

Why is this happening?

I was thrown this error:

> android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Kinda hard to help you if we don't have more information. Does it crash? Does it explode? Does it JUST not show up at all in portrait mode?

Comment: @Jack really sorry about that. It doesn't really crash since I had a try catch. it threw me this error: android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Comment: @Jack i have added it into the question. thanks!

Comment: Did you close the database used by the Cursor?

Comment: @Dan S isn't the cursor created on the fly? from my code I pasted above.

Comment: @Dan S the problem is that everything works fine, I can always create the imageview with the selected image when in landscape mode. but when it gets into portrait mode, nothing works.

Comment: Yes, but the cursor also needs a back end. In a MatrixCursor implementation is this memory and it handles it for a SqliteCursor it is a SqliteDatabase.  The exception suggests that the database for the image needs to be closed and the implementation is a SqliteCursor with a SqliteDatabase.

Comment: Is this happening when you SWITCH to portrait FROM landscape (while running your app)? Or even if you start out in portrait?

Comment: @Jack as long as i hit an image in the gallery when i am in the portrait mode, no matter what orientation i start from, it will not work.